# Python Vanilla Code for simple Logistic regression

Tags: python, scikit-learn, logistic-regression

Given the Coefient and intercept,
How to manually compute the Probability and Predict score for Logistic regression.

```
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
X=data_X.values
y=data_Y

clf = LogisticRegression().fit(X, y)
```

Manual Compute Code with some bug is below

```
import numpy as np

scores=np.array([])
count=0
for x in X:
    score=np.dot(x,clf.coef_[0])+clf.intercept_
    expScore=np.exp(score)
    finalScore=expScore/(1+expScore)
    scores=np.append(scores,finalScore)
    if count<3:
        print(finalScore)
        print(scores)
        count=count+1
scores
```

Since Scores did not match my preict_proba scores, I wana fix my predict Proba code for better understanding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Error was in the formula

```
finalScore=1/(1+expScore)
```